# Lots of Connections by Root User in MySql

Tags: mysql

None of my applications use "root" to connect to MySQL. However, when I fire the command - `SELECT * FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE command != 'Sleep' ORDER BY id`

I see a number of connections which are actually been fired by the root user and the Host is localhost at different ports - please check screenshot  [many connections with root user from locahost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTseq.png)

Is this normal? I see a very high CPU usage, when this happens. I do not have any events running when I have taken the screenshot.

The "Queries" that you see in the info column in the screenshot are actually the queries that are fired from my app which connects to the Database using a different user ID.

Comment: If you're on linux, and you use `netstat -p` as root, you can see the program which has the client ports you're seeing open.  That is a great, easy way to figure out where the connections arecoing from.

Comment: Hi Dan, I am on windows, but I did runt the command - it shows Active Connections - Proto - Local Address Foreign Address - but it was no blank -  which means no connections. When I ran netstat (without the -p) then it gives me a long list with many ports including some which appear in my MySql processlist